# Error while trying to compare two elements (Java)!

Tags: java, generics, comparable

```
class BubbleSort<T>  extends ArraySort<T>
{
    public void iSort(T[] inArray)  {
        int n = inArray.length;
        int k;
        for (int m = n; m >= 0; m--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                k = i + 1;
                if (compare(inArray[i], inArray[k])) {
                    T temp;
                    temp = inArray[i];
                    inArray[i] = inArray[k];
                    inArray[k] = temp;
                }
            }
       }
       print(inArray);
    }
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean compare(T a, T b) {
        if (a.compareTo(b) > 0) {
            return true;
        } return false;
    }
```

I'm getting `(T extends comparable < T >, T extends comparable < T >) in the type bubblesort< T > is not applicable for the arguments (T,T)` error!

The quick fix is telling me to change method `compare(T,T)< T >` to `compare(T,T)`, but that wouldn't resolve my problem. It works perfectly fine when I enter in actual value of elements, for example, `compare(3, 5)` or `compare("hi", "hello")` instead of `compare(inArray[i], inArray[k])`.

I would appreciate it a lot if someone could explain why it's doing that and give me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You've already defined your class with a generic type `T`, so there's no point in declaring a separate one for the method:

```
class BubbleSort<T extends Comparable<T>> extends ArraySort<T> {
    public void iSort(T[] inArray) {
        int n = inArray.length;
        int k;
        for (int m = n; m >= 0; m--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                k = i + 1;
                if (compare(inArray[i], inArray[k])) {
                    T temp;
                    temp = inArray[i];
                    inArray[i] = inArray[k];
                    inArray[k] = temp;
                }
            }
       }
       print(inArray);
    }

    public static boolean compare(T a, T b) {
        if (a.compareTo(b) > 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Anyway, you should denote `T extends Comparable<T>` in the class declaration rather than in the method.

Comment: Holy s#$% thank you! I was about to rip my hair out over this because I knew i had to make change somewhere but couldn't figure it out anyways. We weren't taught well in generics so the only example i had was denoting T extends Comparable in a method so I didn't realize you could do it in the class declaration...

Comment: Feel free to upvote/accept the answer if your problem has been solved!

Comment: `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` would be even better